# How do I a generate a table from doing DateDiff using variables?

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is what I have built so far, but I'm not sure how to finish it. I don't want to create 30-40 calculations measuring the difference between the two dates so I was thinking this could be a way to get the results I want.

```
Varient = 

   GENERATE (
       VAR OctDesign = DATEDIFF(SELECTEDVALUE('SR ID'[Baseline Design Complete]),SELECTEDVALUE('SR ID'[Oct Design Complete]),DAY
       VAR NovDesign = DATEDIFF(SELECTEDVALUE('SR ID'[Baseline Design Complete]),SELECTEDVALUE('SR ID'[Nov Design Complete]),DAY
            RETURN ROW (
            "Nov Design Varient", NovDesign,"
             
            ))
```

Comment: Please provide more detail of what you're trying to do (some sample data and expected results would help)

Comment: I'm just not sure how to finish that syntax? Do you have any idea? What is wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do nor how you want to use that

Comment: I want to get the difference in days between two dates. Thats the table I'm trying to create.

Comment: but a difference between 2 dates is not a table, it's just a measure with a datediff

Comment: What function can I use to create a table with the rows being datediff?